# google apps script runners not calling function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Ive been working on an apps script project for awhile and its been working fine, but suddenly it no longer sends form results back go my .gs script. My code takes an html form to get user input, and passes it back to my script to do work. My code is more complex but the concept is the same as posted below.

```
function test()
{
  var html += '<form id="testform"><input id="testy" type="text" value="enter"><input type="button" value="submit" onclick="google.script.run.printForm();google.script.host.close()" />';
  html += "</form>";
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
     .setWidth(450)
     .setHeight(300);
  Logger.log(html);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'enter anything');
}

function printForm(formObject)
{
  Logger.log("hello?");
  Logger.log(formObject.testy);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("hello world!");
}
```

My problem is that my function, printForm in this case, never gets called. It used to until earlier this week with no significant code changes. No errors get returned, in fact the execution transcript shows the script succeeding.

```
[15-06-27 15:41:58:645 PDT] Starting execution
[15-06-27 15:41:58:657 PDT] HtmlService.createHtmlOutput([<form id="testform"><input id="testy" type="text" value="enter"><input type="button" value="submit" onclick="google.script.run.printForm();google.script.host.close()" /></form>]) [0 seconds]
[15-06-27 15:41:58:659 PDT] HtmlOutput.setSandboxMode([IFRAME]) [0 seconds]
[15-06-27 15:41:58:659 PDT] HtmlOutput.setWidth([450]) [0 seconds]
[15-06-27 15:41:58:659 PDT] HtmlOutput.setHeight([300]) [0 seconds]
[15-06-27 15:41:58:660 PDT] Logger.log([<form id="testform"><input id="testy" type="text" value="enter"><input type="button" value="submit" onclick="google.script.run.printForm();google.script.host.close()" /></form>, []]) [0 seconds]
[15-06-27 15:41:58:660 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getUi() [0 seconds]
[15-06-27 15:41:58:904 PDT] Ui.showModalDialog([HtmlOutput, Select Your Player to Draft]) [0.243 seconds]
[15-06-27 15:41:58:905 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.248 seconds total runtime]
```

Im ripping my hair out trying to figure out what has changed, maybe on google's side, as to why the script runner isnt calling my function. To reiterate, this exact test code worked a week ago along with my larger project that uses similar concepts.

So far Ive tried 4 different browsers, chrome, opera, firefox (which never worked), and IE. Reading around there seemed to be some problem firefox and the script runners, so it makes sense that it still doesnt work.

My TL;DR: In google apps scripts how do you get user input from an html form and pass it back to the server side script if the code above does not?

EDIT: Looking through the apps-script issues Sandy Good linked Im not the only one having a problem of the script runners suddenly not working. Ill update whenever I find out more.

Comment: I used your code, and can confirm that it doesn't work, but it should.  I tried a few different variations of things with no luck.  It's a bug.  You should file an issue.  [Issue Tracker Apps Script](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: Hrm :/ I had a feeling...I only added to a switch that was already there to account for different user input but now it no longer works. I thought maybe google changed how html is handled but it looks the same. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see there where you call the `printForm`, you just open the interface and that's all....You are supposed to call it somewhere....if from the interface, using a `google.script.run.printForm()`. --- Since the interface works asynchronously (in client side), the execution indeed ends when the first method is finished. And the logger doesn't work fof the client side.

Comment: The google.script.run.printForm() should call printForm onclick. Its there if you scroll right, sorry its not ideal line length it was a quick test. My problem is google.script.run.printForm() never calls printForm.